# Join multiple windows in one

Tags: java, windows, join, window-resize, integrator

At the moment, I'm working in a project wich work with two different windows (C# and C++ applications).
I would like to know if anyone knows a way to join and keep resized in another one with Java for example. Are there any integrator app to do this? Is posible to make it with JFrame on my own?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is posible to make it with JFrame on my own?  yes see CardLayout,

Comment: Do you mean that you have separate native applications and you want to put both to one application window? It does not seem to be doable with pure java

Comment: yes AlexR, I only want to take 2 windows and put it together in only one resizable, but I don't know if with Java is possible to move and resize running applications.